# What is your ultimate development environment for working with Dojo widgets?

Tags: dojo

I'm new to working with the Dojo lib and want to know: what's the ultimate development environment to work on Dojo widgets with?

I'm hoping for something with at least JavaScript syntax checking, and code completion support for the standard Dojo widgets and functions.

What development environment -- whether free or purchased -- are you happiest with for such work?

Answer (score 1):

[Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/studio) has both syntax checking and code completion for dojo. For other ideas, please refer to this thread: [JavaScript IDEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41880/javascript-ides).

Answer (score 0):

I use the AJAX Toolkit Framework: JavaScript Development Tools from Eclipse.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/ATF/JSDT

Comment: I used that about a year ago and it acted incredibly unstable.  The only version of it allowed on the project was a couple of years old.  But when I looked into things on the web, the technology almost seemed moribund and abandoned at the time.  Has it gotten rolling again?

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains makes a tool called WebStorm which comes highly recommended:

http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/

If you're working in the J2EE world, you can can these features integrated with IDEA, which is their Java IDE.